# How do infinite scroll pagination in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

I'm making news app in flutter, but api 10 gives news, I just have to pagination but I have no idea how to do it. can you help me?

github link: https://github.com/shahriyar4/news_app

Comment: check this for refrence:  https://www.raywenderlich.com/14214369-infinite-scrolling-pagination-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this package
[pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh)

Here is an example:

```
  List<String> items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
  RefreshController _refreshController =
      RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);

  void _onRefresh() async{
    // monitor network fetch
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    // if failed,use refreshFailed()
    _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
  }

  void _onLoading() async{
    // monitor network fetch
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    // if failed,use loadFailed(),if no data return,use LoadNodata()
    items.add((items.length+1).toString());
    if(mounted)
    setState(() {

    });
    _refreshController.loadComplete();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SmartRefresher(
        enablePullDown: true,
        enablePullUp: true,
        header: WaterDropHeader(),
        footer: CustomFooter(
          builder: (BuildContext context,LoadStatus mode){
            Widget body ;
            if(mode==LoadStatus.idle){
              body =  Text("pull up load");
            }
            else if(mode==LoadStatus.loading){
              body =  CupertinoActivityIndicator();
            }
            else if(mode == LoadStatus.failed){
              body = Text("Load Failed!Click retry!");
            }
            else if(mode == LoadStatus.canLoading){
                body = Text("release to load more");
            }
            else{
              body = Text("No more Data");
            }
            return Container(
              height: 55.0,
              child: Center(child:body),
            );
          },
        ),
        controller: _refreshController,
        onRefresh: _onRefresh,
        onLoading: _onLoading,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (c, i) => Card(child: Center(child: Text(items[i]))),
          itemExtent: 100.0,
          itemCount: items.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```